# How to stop running method from external task in vb.net/c#

Tags: vb.net, exception, task

This is the problem I am facing these days:
I have a test class which has a public method for running test steps. I would like to have a separate task which monitors if control unit rails are opened: if opened I would like to stop immediately the test step execution.

Here is a MWE where I tried to obtain this with exceptions, but it is not working.

```
Module Module1
    Class Test
        Dim t As Task
        Dim i = 0

        Public Sub Monitor()
            While True
                Debug.Print("ok")
                i += 1
                If i > 5 Then
                    'this should be reached when rails are opened
                    Throw New Exception()
                End If
            End While
        End Sub


        Public Sub Step1()
            'this is the test step where rails are closed, thus here I start the monitor
            t = New Task(AddressOf Monitor)
            t.Start()
        End Sub

        Public Sub Step2()
            'this would be any other test step which shall be stopped whenever rails are closed
            While True
                Debug.Print("normal")
            End While
        End Sub

    End Class

    Sub Main()
        Try
            Dim t = New Test()
            t.Step1()
            t.Step2()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print("catch")
        End Try
        Debug.Print("finish") 'I cannot reach this point! How to achieve this?
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: While true will never end, theres no condition.

Comment: Step2 is a while true loop in my MWE but it might be a list of instructions that takes a limited amount of time. In any case I would like to stop Step2 execution as soon as my Monitor detects the fault condition.